# import functions from another jupyter notebook with ipynb fail on terminal command launched with "!"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I use `from ipynb.fs.defs.other_notebook_name import function_name` to import function from an other notebook into my current notebook. It works well to import the function and doesn't run code from the other notebook as expected. But if the other notebook contain a cell with a cmd line invoked with "!" like for example `!pip install pandas` then it raises:

```
! pip install pandas
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I comment every lines with "! ..." from my other notebook then it works.

Do you know a way around this problem: import function from another notebook, while pip installing package in the other notebook ?

Comment: As an aside, if you aren't using Google Colab, you should be using `%pip install <package>` for installing in a cell inside a Jupyter notebook. Anything with an exclamantion point with `pip` or `conda` in Jupyter is outdated. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information on the modern magics that were added to handle installing to the correct environment. Use of the magic versions of `%pip` and `%conda` are now best practice. Avoid use of an exclamation point in combination with `pip` or `conda`.

Comment: As for your question... I see you are using `ipynb` to do the imort. [This issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipynb/issues/6#issuecomment-455041364) seems reported and someone proposed a workaround that only imports certain cells. Have you tried using `importnb` to import, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez)? I just tested it and it had no problem with using magic in front of pip or even an exclamation point. The syntax is different though.

Comment: [This notebook about importnb](https://nbviewer.org/gist/tonyfast/15c6ac8f005a5522291f08d95619e085/2019-09-24-importnb.ipynb) as more examples of `importnb` use than in the Github repo, although it doesn't really show you using the functions from the other notebook which is similar to standard import cases. There's also [subnotebook](https://github.com/davidbrochart/subnotebook).

Comment: I will try importnb tomorrrow (I don't have my computer right now). I juste want to import the finition and ipynb.fs.defs does that (juste run function definitions and import i think). Subnotebook seems interesting for other use but it seems to run the full notebook. So far I changed ``!pip install`` to ``subprocess.call(pip install...``. but I imagine it's not a good workaround as everyone seems to use ! Or % jupyter magic